# how to deploy config files for webapps in jetty 9

Tags: jetty, overlay, config

we are using Jetty Overlay Deployer to install our confings (which defer for testing, dev, prod) along with our binary war files.

According to the documentation this feature has been dropped:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Configuring_the_Jetty_Overlay_Deployer

Is there an recommended alternative for deploying web config into jetty?

Thx

Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post a note on this bug and that should bring it back quicker.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404508

Aside from that you have the normal jetty style of using context xml files to describe things, but nothing quite like the overlay setup in terms of reducing memory usage in multiple iterations of the same webapp being loaded.

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-contexts.html

Comment: I just updated the overlay deployer for jetty 9 and it will show up in 9.0.4